# Position camera relative to plane

Tags: 3d, camera, three.js, position

I have a plane which is positioned at a certain x,y,z position and it is rotated in the 3d space.
I know how to position the camera at its position just setting the same coordinates and rotation, but i would like to put the camera at a certain distance. Can somebody tell me the formula to do this or if it exists a three.js method to achieve the result in the image?

[look at the image of the camera positioned in front of a rotated plane at a certain distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEurW.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can calculate the position of the camera using the vector normal to the plane:

```
camera_position = plane_position + distance_to_the_plane * plane_normal
```

or

```
camera_position = plane_position - distance_to_the_plane * plane_normal
```

to place the camera on the other side of the plane.

After that you can rotate the camera to be pointing along the vector:

```
-plane_normal
```

using **lookAt** member of the camera object

This is the procedure as you asked in your comment:

```
var distance = 100; // for example

camera.position.copy( plane.normal ).multiplyScalar( distance ).add( plane.position );
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
direction.copy( plane.normal ).negate();
camera.lookAt( direction );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am not so advanced in three.js so if you can give practical example would be great. If for example I have the plane like this: plane.x = 100; plane.y = 400; plane.z = 500; plane.rotation.x = 0.4; plane.rotation.y = 0.1; plane.rotation.z = 0.4; camera.position.set(0,0,0); camera.rotation.set(0,0,0); practically what should i write down to normalize and transform into code what you explained to me? Sorry if i didn't understand well, thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, it works! :) do you think it's possible to apply it to css3d rendered div too?